# how can i call js functions(no matter global function or js object method) from oc code via jsContext?

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cocos2d-js

for example , there are some codes in `test.js` file,

```
var test = { var printJS = function () {cc.log("call successfully~!")} }
```

How can i call `printJS` in `AppController.mm` file via JSContext? any help will be appreciated~!

Answer (score 0):

use

`ScriptingCore::getInstance()->executeFunctionWithOwner(jsval owner, const char *name, uint32_t argc, jsval *vp)`

you need to pass the jsobject to c++, that's "var test" in your sample, use it as the first parameter(jsval owner), the second parameter is function name("printJS" in your sample).

i suggest you searching "executeFunctionWithOwner" in your project ,you will find many sample codes in cocos2dx project:)